# How to change the Title and Image of call fragment in Mesibo

Tags: android, mesibo

I have changed the profile image path and able to change it in the Messaging activity. But it doesn’t change in the Call fragment.

So below how can I change the Title (Mesibo Video Call) and Image of the below call fragment with the profile image? [image]

Answer (score -1, accepted):

get the configuration object and change the required fields.

```
MesiboCallConfig mesiboCallConfig = MesiboCall.getInstance().getConfig();
```

You don't need to set object - only change required fields.

Comment: I couldn't find any configuration param to hide "Mesibo Video Call" and changing the default avatar to the user profile picture(whom I am calling).

Comment: There are parameters but since you downvoted my answer, I will not be further responding to this thread.